# in-time hook OpenSaveFileDialog to add Encoding Dropdown

Tags: c#, hook

The OpenFileDialog is opened, when we select File filter *.txt, OpenFileDialog will auto add Encoding Dropdown on OpenFileDialog window. Is it possible in C#?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Watch Notification CDN_TYPECHANGE and add [Dropdown Encoding ComboBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8086/Extending-the-save-file-dialog-class-in-NET) on demand (check ListIndex of "file of Type" ComboBox).

Comment: Hook solution has drawbacks. A file dialog with a custom resource template under Vista (note the extra combo box at the bottom). The dialog is automatically reverted back to the old style.